# .dw directive in AVR assembler

Tags: avr, atmega, assembly

the piece of code below is mentioned in 8-bit AVR's instruction set as an example to explain the LPM instruction.

`ldi ZH, high(Table_1<<1)
   ldi ZL, low (Table_1<<1)
   lmp r16, Z
...
Table_1:
.dw 0x5876
...`

[image: screenshot of the code]

I get that it's trying to load the address of flash memory word, labeled "Table_1", into Z register and then one byte of that word (depending on LSB of Z) into r16 register (or maybe I'm wrong about this part. please correct me if I am). What I don't get is the left shift in the first two lines. Can someone please explain why "Table_1" needs to be shifted left before begin loaded to Z?

Comment: google "avr lpm.pdf" there's an entire application note devoted to your question.  Alternatively "Rev. 3049A–FPSLI–04/02" is the actual Atmel/microchip document.

Comment: Amjal - Although you might have to wait another 24hrs (due to a delay imposed by the site), please remember to *accept* your own answer, so that the site knows that your problem has been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the application note:

"The Z-register in the register file is used to access the program memory. This 16-bit
register pair is used as a 16-bit pointer to the program memory. The 15 most signifi-
cant bits select the word address in program memory. Because of this, the word
address is multiplied by 2 before it is put in the Z register."

Thanks to [isdi](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/201365/isdi) for his comment